# Request response two-way Service Bus

Tags: azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

I have two questions. I need to implement two way communication  between clients and Functions and I am wondering if I should implement their communication using Service Bus or should the clients simply make an Http request to the Azure Function.

The communication will be real-time synchronous so I will need two Queues on the Service Bus as I have seen in the Microsoft Azure code repository but I am thinking that the message will trip too many times using this approach and I should simply http directly to the Function. Using the Service Bus should I make the Queue trigger my functions or should I keep the Function reading the in-queue and writing the out-queue. Is there any advantage using Service Bus on this approach?

The order question is how to make the Functions protected. IF I put everything inside a VPN is enough? Should I implement or use some kind of authentication?

Comment: Please refrain from asking multiple questions in one. You haven't specified why you want Service Bus. By default, use HTTP for sync requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need real-time synchronous, better use HTTP, you don't need Service Bus.

Service Bus is better in decoupled and asynchronous scenarios.